# Фантасти́ческий — фантасти́чный: у меня — синонимы или паронимы?

Tags: синонимы, выбор-варианта, паронимы

> Вероятно, ему льстило церемонное появление в сопровождении целой
>   группы покорных взрослых, которых он принял под своё высочайшее
>   покровительство, и теперь, после его рассказов, нас должны были
>   увидеть вместе в этом городе-деревне везде. По меньшей мере там, где
>   он часто бывал. При этом он успел нещадно перелопатить **мой
>   драгоценный маршрут. И – как выяснится позже – он изменит его на
>   еще более фантастичный**.

Изменение маршрута фантастичное или фантастическое?

---

[Паронимы: фантастический — фантастичный](https://paronymonline.ru/%D0%A4/181)

Не разобралась.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*При этом он успел нещадно перелопатить мой драгоценный маршрут. И – как выяснится позже – он изменит его на еще более **фантастический**.*

Исходные позиции и паронимов таковы. ***Фантастический*** — связанный с фантастикой, вымыслом, сказкой (относительное прилагательное). ***Фантастичный*** —  нереальный, неправдоподобный (качественное прилагательное).

Но относительное прилагательное ***фантастический*** легко переходит в качественное, приобретает значение высокой оценки и даже образует качественное наречие (фантастически прекрасный).

А далее, получив качественное значение, ***фантастический*** начинает вытеснять «соперника» из языка, частотности употребления этих слов в Нацкорпусе просто несравнимы 948:7.

**Слова-синонимы** для этих прилагательных во многом похожи и обычно выражают положительные эмоции (удивление или восхищение): *странный, невероятный,  необыкновенный, поразительный, чудесный.*

Но вот у слова ***фантастичный***  есть синонимы и не очень подходящие для нашего случая: *нелепый, нереальный, надуманный*.

**В результате делаем выбор в пользу прилагательного «фантастический».**

Answer (score 3):

"Фантастический" *по отношению к реальности* (если речь не идёт о смысле "фантастически хороший") означало бы *не соответствующий действительности*, мнимый или кем-то ложно выдаваемый за существующий. С этим словом плохо сочетаются и сравнительные степени, поэтому "фантастичный" здесь убедительнее и может означать "**причудливый**, способный будить воображение, удивлять и восхищать".

Answer (score 1):

Я не поняла, что имел в виду автор при характеристике маршрута.

Фантастический и фантастичный в значении "совершенно неправдоподобный, невероятный, несбыточный" являются синонимами. У вас с автором это значение? Тогда пусть остаётся фантастичный.

Если в значении "причудливый, волшебный, сверхъестественный", то фантастический.

Comment: У автора ночь; сказал: завтра с утра будет во всём разбираться.